# Interactivity with the d3 reusable pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, event-handling, dom-events

In D3:
I'm trying to implement a chart using the [reusable charts pattern](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) which allows me to add events which are handled outside the actual chart. For instance I have a simple barchart where I can click on each individual bar. Now instead of just handling the click event inside the chart component I want to be able to handle it from where I create a chart instance. For example I want to edit the data which corresponds to the clicked bar element or I want to update the position of some other element depending on the position of the bar I clicked on. To keep the chart component as modular and independent as possible I don't want certain tasks to be done inside it.

I came up with a pretty straight forward solution but I feel like there must be a better solution to this. This way I have to account for every possible event that the outside world might be interested in. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hypktL5x/3/)

```
function clickHandler(d, i) {
  // do something with the element/event/data
}

var svg = d3.select('#container')
  .append('svg');

var myChart = chart()
    .onClick(clickHandler);

svg.append('g')
  .datum(data)
  .call(chart);

function chart() {
  var onClick = function() {};

  function _chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(d, i) {

      selection.selectAll('rect')
        .data(d)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * 11;})
        .attr('width', function(d, i) {return d;})
        .attr('height', 10);
        .on('click', _onClick);

    });
  }

  function _onClick(d, i) {
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('fill', 'red');

    onClick(d, i);
  }

  _chart.onClick = function(_) {
    if(!arguments.length) return onClick;
    onClick = _;
    return _chart;
  }

  return _chart;
}
```

Is there any kind of standard way/best practice to handle this type of situation? Or is this just not really a common situation?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is to create a separation between your core application code and code that can be reused. This is a good idea because it keeps your application's code small, making it easier for you to change it and move it forward. In a reusable chart you want to send a very generic events, e.g. `clicked`, while in your application you need the events to be very specific to your domain, e.g. `addSugar`.

There are two ingredients you need: [d3.dispatch](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch) and [d3.rebind](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#rebind). The former helps you create a clear internal API, while the latter helps you expose the dispatched events to the outside world.

Go here to find an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/enjalot/6641917) of this. What you want to look for is three things:

1. Inside the reusable chart you create a dispatcher with events you want to publish to the outside world: `var myDispatch = d3.dispatch('myclick', 'mydrag')`
2. Then in your reusable chart's event handlers you publish these events like so: `myDispatch.myclick(argumentsyouwanttopass)`
3. As a last step you make these events available to the outside: `return d3.rebind(_chart, myDispatch, "on");`
4. Then you can bind to these events on the outside: `myChart.on('myclick', function(){})`

So your example, rewritten could look like this:

```js
function chart() {
  var dispatch = d3.dispatch('click');

  function _chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(d, i) {

      selection.selectAll('rect')
        .data(d)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * 11;})
        .attr('width', function(d, i) {return d;})
        .attr('height', 10);
        .on('click', dispatch.click);

    });
  }

  return d3.rebind(_chart, dispatch, 'on');
}
```

*Additional note:* to register multiple event handlers, you need to namespace them (like you have to for regular d3 events), e.g. `chart.on('click.foo', handlerFoo)`, `chart.on('click.bar', handlerBar)` etc.

Comment: Awesome! I have to wrap my head around this first but it sounds like exactly what I was looking for. Thaanks!

Comment: `d3.rebind()` is not available anymore in D3 library. This answer should be updated with relevant and updated code otherwise not marked as the proper answer

Answer (score 2):

One idea to make it more reusable and applicable to any possible event is to define a `handler` array. This is similar to d3 itself. Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hypktL5x/5/)

```
function chart() {
  var event_handlers = {}; //key value pairs

  function _chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(d, i) {

      var rects = selection.selectAll('rect')
        .data(d)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', function(d, i) {return i * 11;})
        .attr('width', function(d, i) {return d;})
        .attr('height', 10);

        for(var event in event_handlers){
          rects.on(event, event_handlers[event])
        }

    });
  }

  _chart.on = function(event, fun) {
    if(arguments.length==1) return event_handlers[event];
    event_handlers[event] = fun;
    return _chart;
  }

  return _chart;
}
```

You can use your `chart` the same way you use HTML elements.

```
chart.on("click", clickHandler);
```

Comment: Yeah this seems like a pretty good solution! Definitely gonna try that. Thanks